# Is it safe for a service worker to return cached CSP headers containing nonces?

Tags: javascript, security, service-worker, content-security-policy, workbox

I have a Single Page Application written in Angular using a Workbox powered service worker. The static app files are served with a `Content-Security-Policy` header containing a nonce. Static app files (such as `index.html`) which contain `<script>` tags are decorated with a nonce attribute (`<script nonce="FCNjs05n4eQdfn39fn3c9h5segb">`).

Since nonce values **must not** be used more than once, I'm under the assumption that the Service Worker should handle generating new nonce values for each request to static app files by modifying responses delivered from the precache. So, when a request to `index.html` is made, the Service Worker should generate a nonce, modify the CSP header's `script-src` directive to contain the new nonce, and `index.html` must have all `nonce=""` attributes updated to the new nonce as well.

I am assuming this is necessary, as reusing the same nonce value may pose a security risk; however, I am unsure of this as there are no clear security recommendations for this specific scenario. I have found a code example in which the author demonstrates generating a new nonce in the Service Worker using the current Date and the requested file's name (and to my reasoning is not secure, as it does not use cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes).

It should also be noted that I cannot use hashes, as I ran into a hurdle with Mozilla Firefox and Safari. Firefox will only calculate and compare the hash of inline script tag contents with the hashes present in your `Content-Security-Policy` header. The hash of external JavaScript sources (e.g. `<script src="js/foo.js"></script>`) is **NOT** calculated and compared with the hashes you put in your CSP header. This complicates building secured applications, as it requires me to rely on a different security mechanism (nonces), which in turn is requiring me to take extra steps in my server and service worker to rotate these nonce in both headers and the delivered content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem is hidden not in security of generating nonce but in that there is no way to apply nonce generated by service worker (at least I do not see it).

As I understand, an HTTP headers are not stored for cached pages, hence CSP HTTP header will be ignored when page restored from cache. Adding a meta tag into cached page (if it technically is possible) leads that it will be a only one CSP delivered, therefore it should works as expected.

On the other hand , if you add/remove/change `<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content=''>` meta tag, browser does remember and apply all previous policies, see the test. As a result you'll just have a multiple CSPs at one time.
You need to reload page to clear the browser "memory", it's main the SPA's problem with CSP.

But browser behaviour when modifying of cached pages by script, need to be checked additionally. AFAIK there is a method to bypass CSP and nonces via cached pages.

**Update**

In some cases you can use a workaround for external script hashes in Firefox and Safari. You can use an inline script to load the external scripts, like that:

```
var external = document.createElement("script");
external.src = "http://example.com/script.js"
external.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
document.head.appendChild(external);

var external2 = document.createElement("script");
external2.src = "http://example.com/script2.js"
external2.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
document.head.appendChild(external2);
```

The above inline script can be allowed through `'hash-value'` paired with `'strict-dynamic'` (it's a variant of Google's [strict CSP](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html)):

```
script-src 'sha256-hash_of_inline_script' 'strict-dynamic' https:
```

A `'strict-dynamic'` token does allow to load any scripts loaded by legitimate inline script.
Safari does not support `'strict-dynamic'`, therefore it will use `https:` scheme-source to allow external scripts.
Chrome and Firefox do support `'strict-dynamic'`, therefore `https:` will be ignored.

Yes Safari users will be less safe, but you can use real host-sources (`https://example.com https://CDN.com`) instead of `http:`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it appears that my service worker was delivering cached HTTP headers, though that may be because it reached out to the network first (it was a StaleWhileRevalidate caching strategy). I don't have any inline scripts, they are all external scripts, and I'm wondering if I should use hashes for external scripts. It appears there are big inconsistencies specifically around the topic of integrity checks for externally loaded scripts.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about delivery (or not delivery) HTTP headers by a service worker - I did not check that. But in CSP testing I had a troubles with a standard browser cache in Firefox - looks like it restores page from cache without HTTP headers. Also there is a problem with HTTP headers: some ISPs do cache of page and headers - you change a CSP but previous one is applied during a 1-2 weeks for some users. Ref hashes for external scripts - I can confirm that Firefox and Safari did not implement hashes to allow external scripts. You can use a trick - pls see details in the updated answer.

Comment: I did also notice that using the Disable cache option in chrome does not prevent CSP headers from being cached, so while testing you need to constantly be opening and closing the browser. I appreciate the tips, there needs to be more info on this!

Comment: Also, the solution I was trying to produce for Service Workers generating nonces involved writing a workbox plugin. I created the PrecacheController manually and passed my plugin implementing `handlerWillRespond`. Intercept responses with a content type of `text/html`, use RegEx to to replace the old nonces with new nonces, and finally update the headers and return the modified response. The limitation here was the absence of the Crypto API for web workers, so I couldn't generate strong nonces.